# Several ports (8080,8009) are already in use

Tags: java, tomcat

I get this error when running the application in Eclipse:

[image: Example]

Comment: Try changing your Tomcat server's ports.

Comment: You can also run: netstat -atp tcp | grep -i "listen" on OSX, see what uses the port, and kill it if needed.

Comment: Could you help me how to do it Alexey, please?

Comment: I've tried switching to 8081 in server.xml and continues with the same error

Answer (score 0):

The error implies that the ports are already in use ... You probably have another instance of Tomcat running on your machine

Comment: I already changed the doors through own Eclipse IDE from 8080 to 8081, from 8009 to 8010. And the error persists. Can anybody help me???